# Unable to install google-chrome-stable 95 on Centos 7

Tags: google-chrome, dockerfile, centos7, glibc

I'm trying to install the latest version of google-chrome-stable 95.0.4638.54 inside a container with CentOS 7 as base image.

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM centos:7

LABEL maintainer="team@dipcode.com"

ADD ./google-chrome.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo

RUN yum clean all \
    && yum -y install google-chrome-stable
```

The `google-chrome.repo`:

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

When building the Dockerfile, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-95.0.4638.54-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.18)(64bit)
```

As far as I could see, CentOS 7 don't support GLIBC version 2.18 and don't intend to do it.
New versions of Google Chrome will stop supporting CentOS 7? Is there a way to surpass this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem has been solved in a later release of google-chrome-stable.

Comment: Agreed - version 95.0.4638.69-1 now installs just fine via yum.